# Django: efficient filtering in the ORM across ForeignKeys?

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm trying to construct a moderately complex filter in the Django ORM, and I'm not sure if I could do it more efficiently.

My app lets users search for shoes in a particular size. So if they select a size (or multiple sizes), I look for all the shoes available in that size.

This is my model structure. There's an object for each shoe (`Shoe`), an object for each size (`ShoeSize`) (standardised across manufacturers), and an object (`ShoeSizeAvailable`) that only gets created if a particular shoe is available in a particular size.

```
class Shoe(ClothingItem):
  price = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True,db_index=True) ... 

class ShoeSize(models.Model):
  code = models.CharField(max_length=8) ...

class ShoeSizeAvailable(models.Model):
  shoe = models.ForeignKey(Shoe)
  size = models.ForeignKey(ShoeSize)
```

And this is how I currently do the filtering:

```
kwargs = {}
args = ()
if query['price_from']: 
  kwargs['price__gte'] = float(query['price_from'][0])
# Lots of other filters here... 
results = Shoe.objects.filter(*args, **kwargs)

if query['size']: 
    # The query is a list like [6, 6.5]
    # Get all potential ShoeSizeAvailable matches. 
    sizes = ShoeSizeAvailable.objects.filter(size__code__in=query['size'])
    # Get only the ones that apply to the current shoe. 
    shoe_ids = sizes.values_list('shoe', flat=True)
    # Filter the existing shoe results for these values.  
    results = results.filter(id__in=shoe_ids)
```

Is this the most efficient way? I'm concerned that `__in` queries might be inefficient with long lists like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this this way:

```
if query['size']:
    results = results.filter(shoesizeavailable__size__code__in=query['size'])
```