# Filter by twice-removed ForeignKey objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following models: `User`, `UserProfile`, and `SalesCompany`

Relationship: Every `User` has a `UserProfile` and every `UserProfile` has a `SalesCompany`.

I need to get all `User`s at `SalesCompany`s with more than one `UserProfile`.

Is there a more efficient way to do it than my following solution? Some combo of [annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258296/django-models-how-to-filter-number-of-foreignkey-objects) and [traversing `ForeignKeys`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660010/django-efficient-filtering-in-the-orm-across-foreignkeys) seem to be the solution, but I'm stumped.

```
# get all users
all_users = User.objects.all().order_by('username')
users = []
# for each user
for user in all_users:
    try:
        # get profile
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        # get count of profiles (i.e. users) at current user's company
        count_users = len(UserProfile.objects.filter(company=profile.company))
        # if more than one user at company (so not just current user)
        if count_users > 1:
            # add to users list
            users.append(user)
    except Exception, e:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should execute just one SQL query:

```
companies_with_more_than_1_user = (
    Company.objects
        .annotate(num_users=Count('userprofile'))
        .filter(num_users__gt=1)
)
users = User.objects.filter(userprofile__company__in=companies_with_more_than_1_user)
```

Stuff like this is a reason to like the Django ORM, even though I'm generally ambivalent or even slightly disliking towards Django and its way of doing things.

Comment: Glad it worked—it's been 2 years since I last touched any Django code, and I didn't verify the snippet :$